# Flutter Login With Database SQLite

Tags: flutter, sqlite, dart

I a creating a Login page with SQLite, but in the file UserModel in directory lib/models, there is this error:

[image: error]

This is the code:

```
class UserModel {
  String _name;
  String _email;
  String _password;

  UserModel(this._name, this._email, this._password);

  //Receiving data from server
  UserModel.fromMap(dynamic obj) {
    this._name = obj['name'];
    this._email = obj['email'];
    this._password = obj['password'];
  }

  String get name => _name;
  String get username => _email;
  String get password => _password;

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    var map = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    map["name"] = _name;
    map["username"] = _email;
    map["password"] = _password;
    return map;
  }
}
```

Comment: This error has nothing to do with SQLite

Answer (score 0):

Try to store the result in a variable:

```
final result = Usermodel.fromMap('whatever you are sending');
```

Otherwise, I need to see what you are doing behind the help box.

Answer (score 0):

Because the 3 fields `_name`, `_email` and `_password` are of type `String`, an non-nullable type, they always need to have a value. At least before the code from the body of the constructor is executed.

There are different ways to solve this, depending on our needs:
Method 1: provide a default value for the variables

```dart
String _name = '';
```

Method 2: Make the variable nullable

```dart
String? _name;
```

Method 3: Mark the variable as late

```dart
late String _name;
```

Method 4: This is probably the nicest solution. Initialize the variable before the body of the constructor:

```dart
UserModel.fromMap(dynamic obj) : _name = obj['name']{
    
}
```

You can do this for multiple variables:

```dart
UserModel.fromMap(dynamic obj) : _name = obj['name'], _email = obj['email'] 
{

}
```